# Number of non-isomorphic groups of square-free order $n$

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, book-recommendation, online-resources, groups-enumeration

$G$  is a group of order $n=p_1p_2....p_k$ then how to find the number of non-isomorphic groups of order $n$ where $p_i's$ are distinct primes

I can find the number of number of non-isomorphic abelian groups if $G$ has order of this type but how to proceed if $G$ is given to be any group?

Has any research been done in this direction?Where can 
I find it?

Comment: Related question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491408/given-any-n-in-mathbbn-how-many-non-isomorphic-groups-are-there

Comment: Try looking up groups of squarefree order. Here's [something](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57217/subgroups-of-groups-of-square-free-order) (not really exactly what you are looking for but in the same direction)

Comment: Note, you have two different usages of $n$ above. Probably want $n=p_1\cdots p_k$.

Comment: There's also [this](http://www.rose-hulman.edu/mathjournal/archives/2010/vol11-n1/paper7/v11n1-7pd.pdf) reference, that seems to imply that such groups are, in some sense, well understood. Do you mean original research, or does just understanding a rather deep result count as research?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have edited my question regarding $n$

Comment: I mean original research @pjs36

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A000001 and  http://oeis.org/wiki/Number_of_groups_of_order_n.