# amount of non-abelian groups of a certain order

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that there exists a unique group of order $n$ if and only if $(n, \phi(n))=1$. 
I also know how to obtain the number of abelian groups of a certain order

There are exactly 5 groups of order 8, two of them are non-abelian and there are exactly 5 groups of order 12, three of them are non-abelian.

I noticed that $\phi(8)=4=(8,4)$, $\phi(12)=4=(12,4)$ and that $2=\frac{8}{4}$,$3= \frac{12}{4}$.

So, my question is are there exactly $\frac{n}{\phi(n)}$ or $\frac{n}{(\phi(n),n)}$ non abelian groups of order $n$? 
 Or is there any way to know how many non-abelian groups of a certian order there are?

Comment: Your guess is already wrong for $n=6$. There are not $6/\phi(6)=3$ non-abelian groups of order $6$, but just one, namely $S_3$. The question has been asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491408/given-any-n-in-mathbbn-how-many-non-isomorphic-groups-are-there/492028#492028), too.

Comment: Okay so my guess is wrong. In the question you refer me to, I can only find a table of how many non-abelian groups there exist, but they don't show how to obtain those numbers.

Comment: @allizdog That's because those numbers were all obtained through some kind of brute force and exceedingly technical reasoning; counting isomorphism classes of groups is *extremely* hard and, nowadays, computer-assisted in a big way (see [here](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/gnu.pdf) for instance).

Comment: Okay, so brute force is the only way to proceed, thank you!

Comment: See also the classification of finite simple groups: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups